tensorflowjs not found inference
I'm writing a python project to preprocessing audio but when i run it, I have a error:
2024-04-22 00:30:25.847414: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

WARNING:root:TensorFlow Decision Forests 1.8.1 is compatible with the following TensorFlow Versions: ['2.15.0']. However, TensorFlow 2.15.1 was detected. This can cause issues with the TF API and symbols in the custom C++ ops. See the TF and TF-DF compatibility table at https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/main/documentation/known_issues.md#compatibility-table.
WARNING:root:Failure to load the inference.so custom c++ tensorflow ops. This error is likely caused the version of TensorFlow and TensorFlow Decision Forests are not compatible. Full error:D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\tensorflow\ops\inference\inference.so not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflowjs
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflowjs import converters
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflowjs.converters.converter import convert
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflowjs.converters import tf_saved_model_conversion_v2
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tensorflow_decision_forests
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow_decision_forests import keras
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\keras\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from tensorflow_decision_forests.keras import core
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\keras\core.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow_decision_forests.keras import core_inference
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\keras\core_inference.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow_decision_forests.tensorflow.ops.inference import api as tf_op
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\tensorflow\ops\inference\api.py", line 179, in <module>
    from tensorflow_decision_forests.tensorflow.ops.inference import op
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\tensorflow\ops\inference\op.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tensorflow_decision_forests.tensorflow.ops.inference.op_dynamic import *
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\tensorflow\ops\inference\op_dynamic.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise e
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\tensorflow\ops\inference\op_dynamic.py", line 21, in <module>
    ops = tf.load_op_library(resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("inference.so"))
  File "D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py", line 54, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: D:\document\unknow\nam4\hk2\heThongNhung\OnOff\pythonProjectOnOff\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\tensorflow\ops\inference\inference.so not found

I check in file exploier and this file is exist, but python can't find it
Can you help me to fix it?
thank you for your reading and i'm sorry for my English writing
